# post message to users inbox in facebook

Tags: facebook

I am integrating facebook social plugin into our web site. I  follow [This](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) guide line. But one of my requirement is that I should be able to post message to user’s inbox not to wall. Is it possible  JavascriptSDK and GraphAPI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does not permit you to send messages to a user's inbox. As a result, there is a `read_messages` permission, but no `send_messages`.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz. that means there is no way?

Answer (score 0):

Aslong as you application is verified by Facebook the users proxy email address should send all email messages to there inbox

You may also need the 'email' privileged but asking the user to allow the application to send emails.

Comment: Thanks Robert. but this is not facebook app. and i guess there is no such way to verify your web site with facebook?